# I can't find what I want with $search $text MongoDB

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

My json:

```
   {
  user_id: "131231",
  user_name: "John",
  boxes:[
    {
      box_name: "Box 1"
    },
    {
      box_name: "Box 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to find Box 1 with this query:

```
db.users.find({$text: {$search: "Box"}})
```

But mongo can't find anything despite can find `user_name` with this:

```
db.users.find({$text: {$search: "John"}})
```

I tried to `createIndex`.
I'm new in MongoDB. Thank you for all your helps...

Comment: db.users seems to be searching at the root level of the object.  boxes is an array of objects with a properties of box_name.  Your search will not dig into that nested array of objects.  Have you tried to "unwrap the array and project a new set of properties you want to search on?  If you are looking into the array, you would need to search the array - so something like db.users.boxes might work.  Let us know what you have tried and I can post a working sample.

Comment: Did you properly createIndex for the nested object? For example: `createIndex({ 'boxes.boxname' : 'text' });`

Comment: I realised that MongoDB only accept one text index. First of all I deleted all index for this collection by using `db.test2.dropIndex( "*" );` then I just tried `createIndex({ 'boxes.box_name' : 'text' });` then it worked. Sorry about waste your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You index needs to include both fields:

```
createIndex({ 'user_name' : 'text', 'boxes.box_name': 'text' })
```

You ware getting the `IndexOptionsConflict` because on that collection you already had a `text` index and you can't have another one. Once you do the above index these two should work:

```
db.users.find({$text: {$search: "John"}})
db.users.find({$text: {$search: "Box"}})
```

Comment: Thank you @Akrion you are right.By the way if you wanna delete all text indexes you can try `db.users.dropIndex( "*" );`